# Number puzzle : "You can't determine my sum."

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Albert said to Bob, "I have two unequal positive integers; the smaller is at least 2;  the larger is at most 25. I will only tell you their product." So he did. Later, Albert has forgotten the numbers but remembers the other conditions, and remembers their sum.  He says to Bob."I see no way you can determine my sum." WHAT WAS THE SUM?............This was told to me by Michael Korenberg (Ph.D.--matrix theory), who may have composed it. My first thought was that it's paradoxical, but it's not.

Comment: wlg; $2 \le x \lt y \le 25 $. You have $6 \le x\cdot y \le 600 $ and similarly; $5 \le x + y \le 49 $.

Comment: I think you should show that this problem has a single solution. Nevertheless, I guess $x=16$ and $y=15$ since they have a large number of factors.

Comment: This reminds me of a similar puzzle. There's a story that goes along with the puzzle but I'll cut to the chase (you can make up your own story). There are 3 positive integers representing the ages of 3 kids. Their product is 36. Their sum is the number **you can see** on that yellow house over there. Not sufficient? Ok, I'll tell you that the oldest kid plays piano. What are the 3 integers and the number of the yellow house?

Comment: why don't you post it so I can get to see the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Albert tells Bob that, "I see no way you can determine the sum." what he is actually saying is the following, where $S$ is the sum of the two numbers.

- For every pair of numbers $2 \leq a < b \leq 25$ such that $a + b = S$, there is a *different* pair of numbers $2 \leq c < d \leq 25$ such that $a \cdot b = c \cdot d$. (Note that necessarily $a + b \neq c + d$.)

(The existence of this competing pair $c,d$ is what prevents Bob from knowing the sum if the original numbers happened to be $a,b$.)

So we are looking for the sum $S$ which has this property.

For example, $S \neq 15$ because $2 + 13 = 15$ and $2 \cdot 13 = 26$ and this is the *only* pair of numbers in the range which has this product. (So *if* the original numbers happened to be $2,13$ — which is possible as far as Albert is concerned at that point in the story — then Bob would be able to determine the sum because there is only one possible pair with this product which is known to Bob.)

You can brute force this without too much difficulty to show that $S = 11$. There are only four pairs of numbers in the range which have this sum.

- $2 + 9 = 11$, and $2 \cdot 9 = 18 = 3 \cdot 6$.
- $3 + 8 = 11$, and $3 \cdot 8 = 24 = 4 \cdot 6$.
- $4 + 7 = 11$, and $4 \cdot 7 = 28 = 2 \cdot 14$.
- $5 + 6 = 11$, and $5 \cdot 6 = 30 = 2 \cdot 15$.

Comment: If the product is 32, there is no way to get the sum (32 = 8 * 4 = 16 * 2)

Comment: @EugenCovaci But the point is that Albert knows the sum and knows that Bob knows the product. Albert does't know the product Bob has, but can tell that whatever product Bob has, Bob won't be able to work out the sum.

Comment: If the product is 32,Albert may be looking at a sum 12 and not know that  the pair is NOT 5,7 so he wouldn't be sure that Bob did not have a product 35. Similarly for a sum of 18.(18=13+5).